# Using functions in different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When i run my code i get the error: "NameError: name 'distantCity' is not defined" and i'm not sure why it's not defined as i thought i was defining in the load function of Loading.py.

mainGame.py:

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from Loading import *
from characters import *

pygame.init()

class game():

    def __init__(self):

        self.gameRunning = True
        self.gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((gameWindowWidth, gameWindowHeight))
        pygame.display.set_caption(title)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.playerSpeed = speed
        load()

    def update(self):

        self.gameWindow.blit(distantCity, (0,0))
        for layer in gameMap.visible_layers:
            for x, y, gid, in layer:
                tile = gameMap.get_tile_image_by_gid(gid)
                self.gameWindow.blit(tile, (x * gameMap.tilewidth, y * gameMap.tileheight))
        self.gameWindow.blit(ninjaIdle01, (player1.playerX, player1.playerY))
        pygame.display.update()

    def gameLoop(self):

        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        self.event()
        self.update()

    def event(self):

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.gameRunning = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.playerSpeed = 5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.playerSpeed = -5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.playerSpeed = 0
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.playerSpeed = 0

        player1.playerX = player1.playerX + self.playerSpeed

playGame = game()
player1 = player()
while playGame.gameRunning == True:
    playGame.gameLoop()


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Loading.py

```
import pygame
import pytmx

pygame.init()

def load():

    ninjaIdle01 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_01.png")
    ninjaIdle02 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_02.png")
    ninjaIdle03 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_03.png")
    ninjaIdle04 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_04.png")
    ninjaIdle05 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_05.png")
    ninjaIdle06 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_06.png")
    ninjaIdle07 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_07.png")
    ninjaIdle08 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_08.png")
    ninjaIdle09 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_09.png")
    ninjaIdle10 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_10.png")
    ninjaJump01 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_01.png")
    ninjaJump02 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_02.png")
    ninjaJump03 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_03.png")
    ninjaJump04 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_04.png")
    ninjaJump05 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_05.png")
    ninjaJump06 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_06.png")
    ninjaJump07 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_07.png")
    ninjaJump08 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_08.png")
    ninjaJump09 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_09.png")
    ninjaJump10 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaJump_10.png")
    ninjaRun01 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_01.png")
    ninjaRun02 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_02.png")
    ninjaRun03 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_03.png")
    ninjaRun04 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_04.png")
    ninjaRun05 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_05.png")
    ninjaRun06 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_06.png")
    ninjaRun07 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_07.png")
    ninjaRun08 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_08.png")
    ninjaRun09 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_09.png")
    ninjaRun10 = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaRun_10.png")
    distantCity = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_distantCity.png")
    gameMap = pytmx.load_pygame("gameMap.tmx", pixelalpha = True)
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything.  The variables inside the function go out of scope when the function ends/returns.

Comment: Please post minimal examples - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I believe reading about variable scopes [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html) or [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined `distantCity` in `Loading.load`, it remains a local variable. So, you cannot directly access it from outside of that function.

One solution to this is to load all of the data into a dictionary and return that from `load`:

```
def load():
    loaded = {}
    loaded['ninjaIdle01'] = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_01.png")
    loaded['ninjaIdle02'] = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_ninjaIdle_02.png")
    # ...
    loaded['distantCity'] = pygame.image.load("gameImages\s_distantCity.png")
    loaded['gameMap'] = pytmx.load_pygame("gameMap.tmx", pixelalpha = True)
    return loaded
```

Then, in the code that calls `load`:

```
def __init__(self):

    self.gameRunning = True
    self.gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((gameWindowWidth, gameWindowHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.playerSpeed = speed
    self.preloaded_data = load()

def update(self):
    self.gameWindow.blit(self.preloaded_data['distantCity'], (0,0))
    # ...
```

By doing so, you maintain a reference to all of the preloaded data that you can access through the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error i was getting however when i did "tile = self.preloadedData["gameMap"].get_tile_image_by_gid(gid)" that made tile = None instead of the gid number. Is that a problem with the data dictionary or something else? Once again, thanks for the help with problem i had with scope.

Comment: @CustomerSupport I don't have experience with pygame, so I'm not sure what's happening there. Because that issue seems to be entirely separate, I suggest asking a new question – someone else will be able to help you out!